# Login with paypal - redirect_uri wrong?

Tags: paypal

i try to setup "login with paypal" in my magento 1.9.2 shop since 2 days. I did it same like the howto from webformat. I set the return url to 
https://www.xxx.at/loginwithpaypal/ but i get always the failure

> Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request.

whats wrong with my redirect_uri ??

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the `returnurl` in your login with PayPal code does not match the redirect uri in your app.

```
 <script> paypal.use( ["login"], function(login)
     { login.render ({ "appid": "XXX", "authend": "sandbox", "scopes": "openid profile email
 https://uri.paypal.com/services/expresscheckout https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes", 
"containerid": "myContainer", "locale": "en-us", 
"returnurl": "https://www.test/vimal/login_return.php" }); });
 </script>
```

the above reterunurl should match your return url in your app.

[image]